# Login Flows: skip some users and page customisation

Tags: community, force.com-sites, flow, login

i have setup a login flow which works when a user meets the criteria to go through the whole flow. what i cannot do is exclude a subset of users from the start of the flow. this solution seems to take absolutely all users from the specified profile and run them through the flow. I did try setting up my starting element by filtering only users that had a custom field blank on their user record, but the flow is ignoring that filter completely.

I tried skipping the whole flow for users who have gone through it once and get to the end part which is basically a Record Lookup (i saw this solution somewhere on the web) but that just directs my user straight to a page which says "Your flow finished" instead of logging them in.

finally it seems that i cannot edit the default visualforce page in which the login flow is running.

so here are my 2 questions:

- can i skip the flow for some users or have a headless flow for them
- can i edit the visualforce page or use my own within a force.com site ?

Comment: When I experimented with login flows I added a checkbox on the user record that got checked once the login flow has been run once by that user (think accepting terms and conditions). If that box was checked the login flow was skipped. How are you filtering out the users (and/or storing) who shouldn't run the flow?

Comment: so i have an email field that gets filled in on the first login. at the start of the flow my criteria is : lookup user who has userID = LoginFlow_UserId AND custom_email_field is null. i did try emptystring as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be the reason why the flow logic was not respected everytime i created a new version:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XZ5AAM

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that I'ved just tested that works:

1. Lookup the user just using LoginFlow_UserId, assigning the custom_email_field to a text var
2. Then add a decision element that checks if this var is null, if isn't direct to screen if it is don't go through any other element

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. i had arrived to that solution as well. I also found out what the issue was with the flow not working. apparently there is a bug with flows that forces the user to go through it the first time the flow is run just after activating it, but then will apply the correct logic for users after the first run.